# Finding parent class and id

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-events

Well after countless tries I can't get this work?

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("td input").focusout(function() {
      var column = $(this).parent('td').attr('class');
      var row = $(this).parent('tr').attr('id');
      $('#dat').HTML(row+" "+column);
    }); 
</script>
```

And the html looks like this:

```
<tr class="numbers" id="1">
<td class="a" align="right">1</td>
<td class="b"><input class="input" type="text" value=""/></td>
<td class="c"><input class="input" type="text" value=""/></td>

<td class="d"><input class="input" type="text" value=""/></td>
<td class="e"><input class="input" type="text" value=""/></td>
<td class="f">0</td>
<td class="g"><input class="input" type="text" value=""/></td>
</tr>
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction on what might be wrong?

Comment: What's the expected result and what's the current result?

Comment: well i want to extract the td's class for where the inputs is in and what row to be precise

Comment: If you're looking to create a valid HTML document, then you'll need to give the ID a value that starts with a-z/A-Z (http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/types.html#h-6.2).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that it should be lowercase

```
$('#dat').HTML(row+" "+column);
```

`.html`

and

```
$(this).parent('tr')
```

is null, the input can't have a parent TR

alternatively to this you can use

[`.closest( selector, [ context ] )` function](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

Comment: how would i then in a proper way climb up the dom tree to where the tr is then?

Comment: To find the nearest enclosing tr, use .closest('tr'), which will do just that -- climb until it's found.

Comment: `closest` is better than `parents` because it will return only one element, if you had a table inside another the `parents` method would bring wrong results. See http://api.jquery.com/closest/ for a comparative

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
$(this).closest('td').attr('class')
```

at the appropriate spot in your code. Same thing for ID.

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks right for the most part, just fix these things:

```
$('#dat').HTML(row+' ' +column);
```

To this:

```
$('#dat').html(row + ' ' + column);
```

And this:

```
$(this).parent('tr').attr('id');
```

To this:

```
$(this).parents('tr').attr('id');
```

Answer (score 0):

You want to use the `.parents()` function rather than the `.parent()`.

The reason, from the documentation, my highlighting.

> Given a jQuery object that represents
>   a set of DOM elements, the .parent()
>   method allows us to search through the
>   parents of these elements in the DOM
>   tree and construct a new jQuery object
>   from the matching elements. **The
>   .parents() and .parent() methods are
>   similar, except that the latter only
>   travels a single level up the DOM
>   tree.**

Comment: And the reason was the captitalised `.HTML`. But the accepted answer is the best.

Comment: Not only was the .HTML in caps, but the .focusout wasn't working in either Firefox or Opera.

Comment: @Gert G, that surprising. I thought that all of the jQuery functions worked in pretty much every browser.

Comment: nope none of thoose was actually the fault the main reason to why i didnt worked i hadnt capsled the script in
$(function () {
<--script here-->
});